# Caching superclass methods with Spring 3.2 and EHCache

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache, spring-cache

I have the following scenario:

- Spring 3.2
- EHCache
- A superclass that can not be modified (inside a jar), with a structure similar to this:

  ```
  public abstract class SuperClass<E extends Object> implements SuperIface<E> {
      public void insert(E entity) {

      }
  }
  ```
- A subclass, (can be modified), with this structure and a little more complex condition in `@CacheEvict`

  ```
  import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CacheEvict;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

  @Service
  @CacheEvict(value = "entityCache", allEntries = true, condition = "'insert'.equals(#root.methodName)")
  public class SubClass extends SuperClass<Entity> implements ISubIface {
      public void anotherMethod() {

      }
  }
  ```

Is there any option to say Spring to make effective **`@CacheEvict`** annotation when **`insert`** method of **`SuperClass`** is invoked? In other words, Can I remove cache entries when **`insert`** method is invoked from a **`SubClass`** instance?

Note that I'm looking for the way to do it via configuration. I know that I can override superclass' methods in subclass, but for some circumstances (another logic in superclass) I prefer not to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can create [cache advices on any class you want using xml configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache-declarative-xml) if you can't change the source.

Having said that, your example does not make much sense to me: the class is `abstract` so you actually need an implementation to invoke that method. Are you saying that you have multiple implementations and you want all these implementations to have a `CacheEvict` behaviour? If you only have one, I don't see the problem of having an override that merely call `super` + the annotation.

Comment: Superclass has some common CRUD methods (with additional logic) that is shared among his subclasses. Subclases (real services in the application) only specify the parametrized type `<E extends Object>`, and add some custom methods. It would be nice that a class level Cache Annotation in every Service affects not only to his declared methods, but also to inherited "CRUD" methods from abstract Superclass. I could declare multiple cache advice, but I need to do for each of the services.

Comment: `@CacheEvict` at class level makes absolutely no sense to me. It doesn't do anything but surely you don't want that all public methods of said class evict data. I am afraid that if you want to share a cache aspect, you need to be able to say so on the abstract class.

Comment: I don't agree with you. It's true that any Cache annt. at class level could have scope to all methods (even inherited methods), but that doesn't mean you can't control that it affects every single method. All Spring Cache ann. have a `condition` property through you can control in which cases it applies caching, for example, using Spring Expression Language.  `@CacheEvict(value = "entityCache",allEntries = true,condition = "'insert'.equals(#root.methodName)")` it's an example. With this approach, you can specify cache name in every specific Service, and share inherited methods from superclass.